# When can None be used inside a function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a recursive function in python which returns the number of ways to make change for total using coins of value of 1, 5, 10, 25 (as apart of the CS61A course).
I'm using this function to change coins;

```
def next_largest_coin(coin):
    if coin == 1:
        return 5
    elif coin == 5:
        return 10
    elif coin == 10:
        return 25
```

and this function outputs the number of ways;

```
def count_coins(total):
    """Return the number of ways to make change for total using coins of value of 1, 5, 10, 25.
    >>> count_coins(15)
    6
    >>> count_coins(10)
    4
    >>> count_coins(20)
    9
    >>> count_coins(100) # How many ways to make change for a dollar?
    242
    """
    def helper(n, size):
        if n < 4:
            return 1
        elif n < 0 or size > n or size == None:
            return 0
        else:
            if size == 25:
                print(25)
            return helper(n - next_largest_coin(size), size) + helper(n, next_largest_coin(size))
    return helper(total, 1)
```

My code works for the first three test cases, but doesn't work for 100. I've currently concluded that it must be due to the "25" coin trying to increment and thus returning a "None" value, but I've tried to include that condition in my base cases (hence, size == None).

Any thoughts? Is the issue with how I'm using None?

Comment: "but doesn't work for 100" - can you give a bit more detail? What specifically doesn't work? Does the function return the wrong value? Does it raise an error? Etc.

Comment: If none of the three conditions is true, what should the function return?

Comment: Just a side note - this type of problem is more effective using DP - dynamic Programming than recursion, because the later just has too many repeated calculations.

Comment: You are printing 25 rather than returning (or rather, whatever value you want to return for 25).

Comment: please accept an answer @zengho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below my codes for the helper function in the body, which passed the test, I belivev it is truly a tricky problem

```
def helper(m,n):        
    if m == 0:
        return 1
    
    elif m < 0:
        return 0

    elif n == 25:
        with_n = helper(m-n,n)            
        return with_n 
                 
    else:    
        with_n = helper(m-n,n)
        without_n = helper(m,next_largest_coin(n))
        return with_n + without_n
```

Answer (score 2):

The function returns `None` because it doesn't actually return anything (the function reaches no return statement if the parameter is `100`).

You can add an `else` statement to handle all other cases not handled by `if` and `elif`.

Comment: Appreciate that! Any tips on how I would solve this issue without changing the "next_largest_coin" function? The "size == None" statement should catch when the coin increments from 25 to None?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

```py
def next_largest_coin(coin):
    if coin == 1:
        return 5
    elif coin == 5:
        return 10
    elif coin == 10:
        return 25
```

What will this function return, if coin is 2, or 6, or 9, or 11, or any other number not equal to 1 or 5 or 10 ?
You could rewrite your code as follows:

```py
def next_largest_coin(coin):
    if coin == 1:
        return 5
    elif coin == 5:
        return 10
    elif coin == 10:
        return 25
    else:
        raise ValueError("parameter coin has invalid value %d; must be 1 or 5 or 10" % coin)
```

With this code, you will get an error if you pass in a value unequal to 1 and 5 and 10.